Stress-energy tensor for a point particle
I am trying to find the stress-energy tensor for a free particle. Let's start by finding the Lagrangian.
$$ S = -mc \int \sqrt{u^\mu u_\mu} \, ds = -mc \int ds \sqrt{u^\mu u_\mu} \int \delta^{(4)}(x^\mu - x^\mu(s)) \, d \Omega \\
\implies \mathcal{L} = -\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{-g}} \int \sqrt{u^\mu u_\mu} \, \delta^{(4)}(x^\mu - x^\mu(s)) \, ds $$
by definition. Now calculate
$$ \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u^\mu} u_\nu = - \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{-g}} \int \frac{u_\mu u_\nu}{\sqrt{u^\rho u_\rho}} \, \delta^{(4)}(x^\mu - x^\mu(s)) \, ds = -\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{-g}} u_\mu u_\nu \, \delta^{(3)}(x^i - x^i(\tau))
$$
where we used the proper time parametrization and integrated.  
This is clearly the gravitational stress-energy tensor from general relativity since we can integrate it to get the action. 
However, I have seen this expression as the canonical stress-energy tensor in special relativity, but I would say we are missing a piece
$$ T_{\mu\nu} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u^\mu} u_\nu - g_{\mu\nu} \mathcal{L} $$
My guess is that we can discard it since it doesn't affect the conservation law $\nabla^\mu T_{\mu \nu}$. But I can't see why that would be true: we can choose the arc length (proper time) parametrization to get
$$ \nabla^\mu (g_{\mu \nu} \mathcal{L}) = \partial_\nu \mathcal{L} = - \partial_\nu \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{-g}} \int  \delta^{(4)}(x^\mu - x^\mu(\tau))  \, d\tau \\ = -\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{-g}} \int \, \partial_\nu \big( \delta^{(4)}(x^\mu - x^\mu(\tau)) \big) \, d\tau $$
and from distribution theory we know $\frac{d}{dx} \delta(x) = - \delta(x) \frac{d}{dx}$ so we don't get zero.  
A similar situation arises when considering a charged particle in an EM field in special relativity: one can show by direct calculation that
$$ \nabla_\mu (T_{EM}^{\mu \nu} + T_{particle}^{\mu \nu}) = 0 $$
i.e. we can neglect both $ - g_{\mu\nu} \mathcal{L_{particle}} $ and the interaction part $ - g_{\mu\nu} \mathcal{L_{int}} $, both with similar form, but don't know why. 
(Remind that $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L_{int}} }{\partial u^\mu} u_\nu$ is canceled thanks to the symmetrization process for $ T_{EM}^{\mu \nu}$.)

Variables $u^\mu$ are not independent, since $u^\mu u_\mu = -c^2$. So the stationary action solution should be sought within the subset of functions $x^\mu(\tau)$ obeying this condition. This can be done via the Lagrange multiplier method: in the Lagrangian we put another term $\lambda (u^\mu u_\mu + c^2)\delta^{(4)}(x^\mu-x^\mu(\tau))$ , and treat $\lambda$ as unknown function of the wordline parameter. It turns out it can be treated as additional Lagrangian coordinate.
